# How do I feature a book on wiki.ros.org/Books

Tags: ros, documentation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can someone help me create a book page like http://wiki.ros.org/Books/ROS_Robotics_By_Example to be posted on http://wiki.ros.org/Books to feature a book

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254567/how-do-i-feature-a-book-on-wiki.ros.org/books/) by [PacktPub](https://answers.ros.org/users/29347/packtpub/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS wiki is just that, a wiki, so anyone (with an account) can create pages like that.

The procedure would be:

1. register for an account
2. request editing access (<del>[ros-infrastructure/roswiki#139](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/roswiki/issues/139)</del> [ros-infrastructure/roswiki#258](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/roswiki/issues/258) now)
3. create a new page
4. link to it from the `Books` page

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ohsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/52268/ohsh/) on 2020-03-08**:
Thank you for good information.